# HandShake Failure On a supported Version

Tags: ssl, network-protocols, scapy, tls1.2

I am trying to determine whether TLS_1_2 is  supported version on a website or not i.e (portal.threatpulse.com,443)

```
from scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls import *

target = (portal.threatpulse.com,443)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(target)
pkt = TLSRecord(version = 'TLS_1_2')/TLSHandshake()
     /TLSClientHello(version = 'TLS_1_2')
sock.sendall(str(pkt))
resp_pkt = sock.recv(8192)
resp = SSL(resp_pkt)
resp.show()
```

It is giving me handshake failure even though this version is supported.
this code is running correctly other than this

Comment: cipher_suites=[TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
i also tried using this cipher suite which is supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since today's certificates usually have a SHA-256 signature the server requires that the client supports RSA/SHA-256 as signature/hash algorithms. But this combination is not included in the default set of the `SignatureAndHashAlgorithm` TLS extension which is new with TLS 1.2. This default set includes only  (SHA-1 with RSA, DSA or ECDSA. If a TLS 1.2 client supports more or different algorithms than the default it is required to include the `SignatureAndHashAlgorithm` extension and explicitly announce support for this signature/hash pair. With the following code this specific site works for me, but for other sites you might need to extend this to include ECDSA too.

```
pkt = TLSRecord(version = 'TLS_1_2') / \
    TLSHandshake() / \
    TLSClientHello(
        version = 'TLS_1_2',
        extensions=[ TLSExtension() / \
            TLSExtSignatureAndHashAlgorithm( algorithms = [
                TLSSignatureHashAlgorithm(
                    hash_algorithm = TLSHashAlgorithm.SHA256,
                    signature_algorithm = TLSSignatureAlgorithm.RSA
                )
            ])
        ]
    )
```

Comment: it is giving me KeyError: 'hash_algorithm'

Comment: @hassan_anwer: that's exactly how it works for me with the latest version of scapy_ssl_tls, freshly installed with pip. This is just copied from my working test program.

Comment: I also installed fresh version from pip but still giving me key error.
Can u plz review or run this small piece of code, it will be helpful for me
http://www.filedropper.com/tlsscan

Comment: @hassan_anwer: your script works for me unchanged on python 2.7.12, scapy 2.3.2, scapy_ssl_tls 1.2.2 (i.e. all the latest)